# Помогите найти ошибку в написании if - else

Tags: php

Ку, есть условие if которое почему то не срабатывает,

Значение: $region = 'Севастополь' и по сути должен выполнятся else, а все равно проходит условие и прорабатывает скрипт. Подскажите куда посмотреть..,

```
public static function refleshPosition($site_id = null): string
    {
        if (isset($site_id)) {
            $site = systems::$db->select('site', ['id', 'region', 'topvisor_id', 'domen'], ['id' => $site_id])[0];
            $yandex = topvisor::getPosition($site['topvisor_id'], 'Yandex', $site['region']);
            echo $site['region'];
            $region = str_replace(' ', '', $site['region']);
            if ($region !== 'Севастополь' or $region !== 'Симферополь' or $region !== 'Керчь' or $region !== 'Евпатория' or $region !== 'Ялта') {
                echo 'а я вызываюсь';
                $google = topvisor::getPosition($site['topvisor_id'], 'Google', $site['region']);
                $result = array(
                    'yandex' => $yandex,
                    'google' => $google,
                );
            } else ($result = array(
                'yandex' => $yandex,
                'google' => '',
            ));
        }
        $result = serialize($result);
        systems::$db->update('site', ['position' => $result], ['id' => $site_id]);
        return "<p>Позиции обновлены</p>";
    }
```

Comment: У Вас секция `else` обёрнута обычными скобками, а не фигурными...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$region !== 'Севастополь' or $region !== 'Симферополь'
```

Условие: регион не Севастополь ИЛИ не Симферополь.

Допустим регион 'Севастополь', очевидно что, Севастополь это не Симферополь, второй предикат принимает значение TRUE и все условие становится TRUE

Далее возможны варианты:

```
$regions = ['Севастополь','Симферополь','Керчь','Евпатория','Ялта'];
```

1. Регион один из $regions: `in_array($region, $regions);`
2. Регион ни один из $regions: `!in_array($region, $regions);`

Comment: аааааа... вот оно как работает, спасибо

Comment: Если я сделаю не !== а наоборот == то получается у меня логика сойдеться ? Спасибо!!

Comment: @Леонид Басов Все зависит от того, что вы хотите получить.

Comment: попробую) в любом случае спасибо!

Comment: @Леонид Басов дополнил ответ